# How to automate versioning of Maven project in GitHub?

Tags: maven, github, workflow, release, versioning

I am trying to make auto- or semi-auto versioning into `GitHub`.

I looked into the automation release workflow possibilities and it doesn't seem like anything standard for `GitHub`.

I want to have an automatic update of version in `pom.xml` whenever I create a tag on `GitHub` or whenever I merge into the `master` branch.

Comment: There at least two ways: First via maven-release-plugin or via [CI Friendly way](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html)

Comment: @khmarbaise do I understand correctly that plugin controls `ci` but and generate tag but not `bump` `${project.version}` automatically? It would be nice to bump the version of project as well and based on this create release tags.

Comment: The version is dynamically given via property on command line. It is not part of your pom file anymore ...The tags must be done manually or external script. If you like to have the version in your pom file you can do that via maven-release-plugin including tagging etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a workaround solution with Github Actions that can be extended further. Whenever I release and I manually specify release notes and changelog, so this release version can be taken from `github.event.release.tag_name`

```
mvn -B versions:set -DnewVersion=${{ github.event.release.tag_name }} -DgenerateBackupPoms=false
```

The reference to the actual GitHub workflow is [here](https://github.com/ChameleonTartu/amazon-mws-reports-maven/blob/master/.github/workflows/deploy.yml).

`.github/workflows/deploy.yml` at the time of writing:

```
name: Publish package to the Maven Central Repository
on:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out Git repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Java and Maven
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 8
      - if: github.event.release
        name: Update version in pom.xml (Release only)
        run: mvn -B versions:set -DnewVersion=${{ github.event.release.tag_name }} -DgenerateBackupPoms=false
      - name: Release Maven package
        uses: samuelmeuli/action-maven-publish@v1.4.0
        with:
          maven_profiles: deploy, verify
          gpg_private_key: ${{ secrets.GPG_PRIVATE_KEY }}
          gpg_passphrase: ${{ secrets.GPG_PASSPHRASE }}
          nexus_username: ${{ secrets.OSSRH_USERNAME }}
          nexus_password: ${{ secrets.OSSRH_TOKEN }}
```